# What is the httpd process on Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS?

Tags: server, apache2

I have got fresh Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS, then I install apache2, using `sudo apt-get apache2 install`. But I was not able to run apache using `sudo service apache2 stop/start/restart` because of errors:

```
make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

This gave me the thing that port 80 is busy because some process uses it. When I tried `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep '80'` there always was the httpd process, even after I completely deleted the apache:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      107986/httpd
```

What is this httpd process ? Why I can't run the apache ?

The process info is:

```
4 S root      17522  17492  0  80   0 - 13757 -       4940   0 09:47 ?        00:00:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/13144 -k start -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: I think that comes pre-installed in the server edition!

Comment: Do you mean apache preinstalled ? or some httpd ? As I see now apache is not preinstalled, but httpd process is there

Comment: Run `sudo systemctl status apache2`!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because there was installed nextcloud and used port 80. I was removed nextcloud because I don't need it.

Comment: Please read: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-nextcloud-15-on-ubuntu-server-18-04/